# University's logo

Tags: graphics, formatting, titles

How to put the logo before the date and after my name in the title? I write it as

```
 \begin{document}

 \title{}

 \author{}

 \titlepic{ \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}

 \date{}
```

but it appears after the date!!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Please expand your minimal working example, in particular it would be good to know the document class.

Comment: The thing to remember about `\title` and `\author` is that they don't produce any output by themselves.  They just save their argument in a macro to be expanded later.  The `\maketitle` macro expands these saved macros.

Comment: Aside: Some universities have strict (not to say *freaking ridiculous*, Bama) guidelines concerning the use of their logos and layout or typographical conventions to be employed when you use it. You might want to have a look around to make sure you won't get in trouble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `\author` field; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\title{The Title}
\author{%
  The Author \\
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}%
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the optional argument for `\\` (as in `\\[1cm]`, `\\[-3pt]`) you can 
control the vertical space between the author name and the logo.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do not use that option in your actual document.

As **Matthew Leingang** mentions in a comment, some packages will do things with the contents of the `\author` declaration, like put it into the PDF metadata. Declaring the author of the document to be `The Author \\ \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}` spoils this extra functionality and will require extra adjustments.

Comment: This definitely does the trick but it breaks the semantic markup of the document.  Some packages will do things with the contents of the `\author` declaration, like put it into the PDF metadata.  Declaring the author of the document to be `The Author \  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}` spoils this extra functionality.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I partially agree with your comment; the PDF metadata can be fixed so as to not include whatever results from the image; some document classes offer an optional argument for `\author`...

Comment: @MatthewLeingang In some minutes I will add a remark to my answer including the remark in your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

We can also use the `titling` package to add a new element to `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\logo}[1]{%
  \postauthor{%
  \end{tabular}\par\end{center}
  \begin{center}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{#1}\end{center}
  \vskip0.5em}%
}

\title{We love ducks}
\author{Daffy Duck}
\logo{quackuniversity}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Moar duckz]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: One might consider using something like `\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]` instead of `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]` to be independent of image size.

Answer (score 6):

You can redefine the `\maketitle` as it is done by the titlepic package.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlepic}
%
\makeatletter
%% This is a redefinition of the contents of titlepic.sty file
\if@titlepage
\renewcommand\maketitle{
    \begin{titlepage}%
        \let\footnotesize\small
        \let\footnoterule\relax
        \let \footnote \thanks
        \@tptopspace%
        \begin{center}%
            {\LARGE \@title \par}%
            \vskip 3em% %% Change this space if you wish
            {\large
                \lineskip .75em%
                \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \@author
                \end{tabular}\par%
            }%
%         \@tpsepspace% %% uncomment if you need space.
        {\centering\@titlepic\par}
            \vskip 1.5em%   %% Change this space if you wish
            {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
        \end{center}\par
        \vfil
        \@thanks
    \end{titlepage}%
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
    \global\let\thanks\relax
    \global\let\maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@thanks\@empty
    \global\let\@author\@empty
    \global\let\@date\@empty
    \global\let\@title\@empty
    \global\let\@titlepic\@empty
    \global\let\title\relax
    \global\let\author\relax
    \global\let\date\relax
    \global\let\and\relax
    \global\let\titlepic\relax
}
\fi
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\title{My title}
%
\author{My name}
%
\titlepic{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}}
%
\date{\today} 
%
\maketitle
%
\end{document}
```

[image]