# How to customise the title page of a professional writing with logo?

Tags: titles, thesis, big-list, logos

Title page customising is a repeating activity: whether writing thesis, a company report or something else. I am trying to gather here material suggested in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18700184#18700184) and that I found so they do not get lost.

**How to customise the title page of a professional writing with logo?**

Comment: Maybe the question should be a `big-list` and/or community wiki? It doesn't seem likely to have a unique best solution, does it?

Comment: @cfr good point, probably not -- how can you make it community wiki question? I am hoping that people with similar goals as me here will be working on this, I will be working surely so making information more accessible :)

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea. Ask somebody in chat?

Answer (score 1):

Be welcome to suggest more relevant material. I think the first is the coolest thread I found so far.

> 1. [Where to put the institute information in the article document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/where-to-put-the-institute-information-in-the-article-document-class)
> 2. [How to customize my titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-add-a-flyleaf-code)
> 3. [University's logo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66087/universitys-logo)